# How to convert an 500GB SQL table into Apache Parquet?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, hadoop, parquet

Perhaps this is well documented, but I am getting very confused how to do this (there are many Apache tools).

When I create an SQL table, I create the table using the following commands:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name(
   column1 datatype,
   column2 datatype,
   column3 datatype,
   .....
   columnN datatype,
   PRIMARY KEY( one or more columns )
);
```

How does one convert this exist table into Parquet? This file is written to disk? If the original data is several GB, how long does one have to wait?

Could I format the original raw data into Parquet format instead?

Comment: For the record, Sqoop has no real future now that Spark is gaining momentum as a "general purpose ETL engine for Hadoop and beyond" *(Sqoop was developed by Cloudera as a stop-gap solution, but Cloudera is now championing Spark...)*

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Apache Spark can be used to do this:

```
1.load your table from mysql via jdbc
2.save it as a parquet file
```

Example:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
df = spark.read.jdbc("YOUR_MYSQL_JDBC_CONN_STRING",  "YOUR_TABLE",properties={"user": "YOUR_USER", "password": "YOUR_PASSWORD"})
df.write.parquet("YOUR_HDFS_FILE")
```

Comment: Excellent! Thanks for this

Comment: How do we check the progress of this save? This command is stuck from half hour in my machine?? the size of the db is 44 gb.

Comment: @Viv you can check the spark job web page for detailed task info,normally it runs at localhost:8080

Comment: My personal experience tells that to be able to use this solution, you need to be aware of these two gotchas: 1. **No of parallel queries** your `MySQL` DB instance can handle 2. The **`JDBC` driver** that you use with `Spark`, should be able to use a **high `fetchSize`** (like 10k)

Comment: The connection works, but when trying to pull the whole table from mysql, I got: java.sql.SQLException: GC overhead limit exceeded. Any of you have the same issue?

Comment: I get the following error when doing this on my mac; let me know of any suggestions: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver

Answer (score 4):

The [`odbc2parquet`](https://github.com/pacman82/odbc2parquet) command line tool might also be helpful in some situations.

```sh
odbc2parquet \
-vvv \ # Log output, good to know it is still doing something during large downloads
query \ # Subcommand for accessing data and storing it
--connection-string ${ODBC_CONNECTION_STRING} \
--batch-size 100000 \ # Batch size in rows
--batches-per-file 100 \ # Ommit to store entire query in a single file
out.par \ # Path to output parquet file
"SELECT * FROM YourTable"
```

Answer (score 0):

Another memory-saving option is to use streaming SQL query results with SQLAlchemy and gradually append them to the parquet file with PyArrow.
In [SQLAlchemy](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/connections.html#using-server-side-cursors-a-k-a-stream-results) set your `Connection.execution_options.stream_results = True` and then fetch rows in chunks with `Result.yield_per()`.
For each iteration put fetched rows to `pyarrow.Table` and use `pyarrow.parquet.ParquetWriter.write_table` to append it to the file